# How to print integers in ascending order from a balanced binary search tree?

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, binary-search-tree

This a program creates balanced binary search tree from an array integer and later on, prints the value in-order ( X.left, X, X.right). Any suggestion for improving the program appreciated.

It would be good to note, there are several other ways for traversing a BST. Such as -
Pre-order : X, X.left, X.right
Post-order : X.left, X.right, X

Note # I eventually solved the issue with some help from the user of this program. It needed to change some conditions inside the *createMinimalBST* method.

```
// we need to stop recursion there as one element exist
if (start == mid-1) {

}

// we need to stop recursion there as one element exist
if (end == mid+1) {

}
```

THANK YOU.

```
// import java.util.Arrays;
// import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.*; 

class Node {

    int key;

    Node leftChild;
    Node rightChild;

    Node(int key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    Node() {
        // null constructor 
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "\n"+key+" ";
    }
}


public class BinaryTree {

    Node root;

    static int TWO_NODES_FOUND = 2;
    static int ONE_NODE_FOUND = 1;
    static int NO_NODES_FOUND = 0;

    BinaryTree (){
        root = null;
    }

    public void addNode(int key) {

        Node newNode = new Node(key);

        // If there is no root this becomes root
        if (root == null) {
            root = newNode;
        } 

        else {

            // Set root as the Node we will start
            // with as we traverse the tree

            Node focusNode = root;
            Node parent;

            while (true) {

                parent = focusNode;

                if (key < focusNode.key) {

                    focusNode = focusNode.leftChild;

                    if (focusNode == null) {

                        parent.leftChild = newNode;
                        return; // All Done
                    }
                } // end of if 

                else { 

                    focusNode = focusNode.rightChild;

                    if (focusNode == null) {

                        parent.rightChild = newNode;
                        return; 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // get the height of binary tree 
    public int height(Node root) {

        if (root == null)
            return -1;

        Node focusNode = root; 
        int leftHeight = focusNode.leftChild != null ? height( focusNode.leftChild) : 0;
        int rightHeight = focusNode.rightChild != null ? height( focusNode.rightChild) : 0;
        return 1 + Math.max(leftHeight, rightHeight);
    }

    // METHODS FOR THE TREE TRAVERSAL

    // inOrderTraverseTree : i) X.left ii) X iii) X.right
    public void inOrderTraverseTree(Node focusNode) {

        if (focusNode != null) {

            inOrderTraverseTree(focusNode.leftChild);
            // System.out.println(focusNode);
            System.out.print( focusNode );
            inOrderTraverseTree(focusNode.rightChild);
        }
        // System.out.println();
    }

    // preOrderTraverseTree : i) X ii) X.left iii) X.right
    public void preorderTraverseTree(Node focusNode) {

        if (focusNode != null) {

            System.out.println(focusNode);
            preorderTraverseTree(focusNode.leftChild);
            preorderTraverseTree(focusNode.rightChild);

        }
    }

    // postOrderTraverseTree : i) X.left ii) X.right iii) X
    public void postOrderTraverseTree(Node focusNode) {

        if (focusNode != null) {

            preorderTraverseTree(focusNode.leftChild);
            preorderTraverseTree(focusNode.rightChild);
            System.out.println(focusNode);

        }
    }

    // get certain node from it's key
    public Node findNode(int key) {

        Node focusNode = root;

        while (focusNode.key != key) {

            if (key < focusNode.key) {

                focusNode = focusNode.leftChild;

            } else {

                focusNode = focusNode.rightChild;
            }

            if (focusNode == null)
                return null;
        }
        return focusNode;

    }


    public boolean remove(int key) {

        Node focusNode = root;
        Node parent = root;
        boolean isItALeftChild = true;


        // we will remove the focusNode 
        while (focusNode.key != key) {

            parent = focusNode;

            if (key < focusNode.key) {

                isItALeftChild = true;
                focusNode = focusNode.leftChild;
            } 

            else {

                isItALeftChild = false;
                focusNode = focusNode.rightChild;
            }

            if (focusNode == null)
                return false;
        }

        // no child 
        if (focusNode.leftChild == null && focusNode.rightChild == null) {

            if (focusNode == root)
                root = null;

            else if (isItALeftChild)
                parent.leftChild = null;

            else
                parent.rightChild = null;
        }

        // one child ( left child )
        else if (focusNode.rightChild == null) {

            if (focusNode == root)
                root = focusNode.leftChild;

            else if (isItALeftChild)
                parent.leftChild = focusNode.leftChild;

            else
                parent.rightChild = focusNode.leftChild;
        }


        else if (focusNode.leftChild == null) {

            if (focusNode == root)
                root = focusNode.rightChild;

            else if (isItALeftChild)
                parent.leftChild = focusNode.rightChild;

            else
                parent.rightChild = focusNode.rightChild;

        }

        // two children exits 
        else {

            // replacement is the smallest node in the right subtree 
            // we neeed to delete the focusNode 
            Node replacement = getReplacementNode(focusNode);

            if (focusNode == root)
                root = replacement;

            else if (isItALeftChild)
                parent.leftChild = replacement;

            else
                parent.rightChild = replacement;

            replacement.leftChild = focusNode.leftChild;
        }

        return true;
    }



    public Node getReplacementNode(Node replacedNode) {

        Node replacementParent = replacedNode;
        Node replacement = replacedNode;
        Node focusNode = replacedNode.rightChild;

        // find the smallest node of the right subtree of the node to be deleted 
        while (focusNode != null) {

            replacementParent = replacement;
            replacement = focusNode;
            focusNode = focusNode.leftChild;
        }

        // exit when the focusNode is null
        // the replacement is the smallest of the right subtree

        if (replacement != replacedNode.rightChild) {

            replacementParent.leftChild = replacement.rightChild;
            replacement.rightChild = replacedNode.rightChild;
        }

        return replacement;
    }


    private  void createMinimalBST(int arr[], int start, int end, Node newNode){

        if ( end <= start ) return;

        int mid = (start + end) / 2;
        newNode.key = arr[mid];

        // System.out.println("new node = "+ newNode );

         if (start <= mid-1) {
            if ( start < mid-1){
                newNode.leftChild = new Node();
                createMinimalBST( arr, start, mid - 1, newNode.leftChild );
            }
            else {
                newNode.leftChild = new Node();
                newNode.leftChild.key = arr[start];
            }
        }

        if ( mid+1 <= end ) {

            if ( mid+1 < end){

                newNode.rightChild = new Node();
                createMinimalBST(arr, mid + 1, end, newNode.rightChild); 
            }

            else {
                newNode.rightChild = new Node();
                newNode.rightChild.key = arr[end];
            }
        }

        // System.out.println("left child = "+ newNode.leftChild +" "+ " right child = "+ newNode.rightChild);        

    } 

    public static int getHeight(Node root) {
        if (root == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return Math.max(getHeight(root.leftChild), getHeight(root.rightChild)) + 1;
    }

    public static boolean isBalanced( Node root) {
        if (root == null) {
            return true;
        }
        int heightDiff = getHeight(root.leftChild) - getHeight(root.rightChild);

        if (Math.abs(heightDiff) > 1) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return isBalanced(root.leftChild ) && isBalanced(root.rightChild );
        }       
    }

    public void createMinimalBST(int array[]) {

        // Node n = new Node();
        Arrays.sort(array);
        root = new Node();
        createMinimalBST(array, 0, array.length - 1, root);
    }

    // create linked list of the same level of the tree
    public static ArrayList<LinkedList<Node>> createLevelLinkedList( Node root) {

        ArrayList<LinkedList<Node>> result = new ArrayList<LinkedList<Node>>();

        /* "Visit" the root */
        LinkedList<Node> current = new LinkedList<Node>();

        if ( root != null) {
            current.add(root);
        }

        while ( current.size() > 0) {

            result.add(current); // Add previous level
            LinkedList<Node> parents = current; // Go to next level

            current = new LinkedList<Node>(); 

            for ( Node parent : parents) {

                /* Visit the children */
                if (parent.leftChild != null) {
                    current.add(parent.leftChild);
                }

                if (parent.rightChild != null) {
                    current.add(parent.rightChild );
                }
            }   

        }

        return result;
    }

    // print values in the same level of the tree gradually 
    public static void printResult(ArrayList<LinkedList<Node>> result){

        int depth = 0;      

        for(LinkedList<Node> entry : result) {

            Iterator<Node> i = entry.listIterator();
            System.out.print("Link list at depth " + depth + ":");

            while(i.hasNext()){
                System.out.print(" " + ((Node)i.next()).key );
            }

            System.out.println();
            depth++;    
        }       
    }


    // using a key, check whether the node is inside of the BST or not 
    public boolean isBST (int n){

        if ( n == root.key ){
            return true;
        }

        else {

            Node focusNode = root;
            Node parent; 

            while( focusNode != null){

                parent = focusNode;

                if (focusNode != null){

                    if (n < focusNode.key){

                        focusNode = focusNode.leftChild;
                    }

                    else {

                        focusNode = focusNode.rightChild;

                    }
                }

                if ( focusNode != null &&   n == focusNode.key ){
                    return true;

                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    // 
    public Node getNode (int n){

        if ( n == root.key ){
            return root;
        }

        else {

            Node focusNode = root;
            Node parent; 

            while( focusNode != null){

                parent = focusNode;

                if (focusNode != null){

                    if (n < focusNode.key){

                        focusNode = focusNode.leftChild;
                    }

                    else {

                        focusNode = focusNode.rightChild;

                    }
                }

                if ( focusNode != null &&   n == focusNode.key ){
                    return focusNode;

                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    // get the parent of using the key of certain node 
    public Node getParent (int n){

        if ( !isBST (n)){
            return null;
        }

        if ( n == root.key ){
            return null;
        }

        else {

            Node focusNode = root;
            Node parent; 

            while( focusNode != null){

                parent = focusNode;

                if (focusNode != null){

                    if (n < focusNode.key){

                        focusNode = focusNode.leftChild;
                    }

                    else {

                        focusNode = focusNode.rightChild;

                    }
                }

                if ( focusNode != null && n == focusNode.key ){
                    return parent;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }


    /* get in-order successive node of the certain node */
    public  Node inorderSucc( Node n) { 

        if (n == null) return null;

        // Found right children -> return left most node of right subtree
        if ( getParent(n.key)    == null || n.rightChild != null) { 
            return leftMostChild( n.rightChild ); 
        } 

        else { 

            Node q = n;
            Node x = getParent(q.key);

            // Go up until we’re on left instead of right
            while (x != null && x.leftChild != q) {
                q = x;
                x = getParent(x.key);
            }
            return x;
        }  
    } 

    /* get the left most/ smallest node of the sub tree of the certain node */
    public  Node leftMostChild( Node n) {

        if (n == null) {
            return null;
        }

        while (n.leftChild != null) {
            n = n.leftChild; 
        }
        return n; 
    }


    // SECOOND SOLUTION TO FIND OUT THE COMMON ANCESTOR OF TWO NODES 

    public static boolean covers2( Node root, Node p) { 

        if (root == null) return false;
        if (root == p) return true;
        return covers2(root.leftChild , p) || covers2(root.rightChild , p); 
    }

    public static Node commonAncestorHelper( Node root, Node p, Node q) {
        if (root == null) {
            return null;
        }
        boolean is_p_on_left = covers2(root.leftChild , p);
        boolean is_q_on_left = covers2(root.leftChild , q);
        if (is_p_on_left != is_q_on_left) { // Nodes are on different side
            return root;
        }

        // nodes are the same sides
        Node child_side = is_p_on_left ? root.leftChild : root.rightChild;
        return commonAncestorHelper(child_side, p, q);

    }

    public static Node commonAncestor2( Node root, Node p, Node q) {

        if (!covers2(root, p) || !covers2(root, q)) { // Error check - one node is not in tree
            return null;
        }
        return commonAncestorHelper(root, p, q);
    }
    // END OF THE SECOND SOLUTION 


    // FIRST SOLUTION TO FIND OUT THE COMMON ANCESTOR OF TWO NODES
      // Checks how many “special” nodes are located under this root
    public static int covers( Node root, Node p, Node q) {
        int ret = NO_NODES_FOUND;
        if (root == null) return ret;
        if (root == p || root == q) 
            ret += 1;
        ret += covers(root.leftChild , p, q);
        if(ret == TWO_NODES_FOUND) // Found p and q 
            return ret;
        return ret + covers(root.rightChild , p, q);
    }


    public static Node commonAncestor( Node root, Node p, Node q) {

        if (q == p && (root.leftChild == q || root.rightChild == q)) 
            return root;

        int nodesFromLeft = covers(root.leftChild, p, q); // Check left side

        if ( nodesFromLeft == TWO_NODES_FOUND ) {

            if(root.leftChild == p || root.leftChild == q) 
                return root.leftChild;
            else return commonAncestor(root.leftChild , p, q);
        } 

        else if (nodesFromLeft == ONE_NODE_FOUND) {

            if (root == p) return p;
            else if (root == q) return q;
        }

        int nodesFromRight = covers(root.rightChild, p, q); // Check right side

        if(nodesFromRight == TWO_NODES_FOUND) {

            if(root.rightChild == p || root.rightChild == q) 
                return root.rightChild;

            else return commonAncestor(root.rightChild , p, q);
        } 

        else if (nodesFromRight == ONE_NODE_FOUND) {
            if (root == p) return p;
            else if (root == q) return q;
        }

        if (nodesFromLeft == ONE_NODE_FOUND && 
            nodesFromRight == ONE_NODE_FOUND) return root;
        else return null;
    }
    // END OF THE FIRST SOLUTION 


    // METHODS FOR SUBTREE CHECK 
    // Check if T2 is subtree of T1     
    public static boolean containsTree( Node t1, Node t2) {
        if (t2 == null)
            return true; // The empty tree is a subtree of every tree.
        else
            return subTree(t1, t2);
    }


    /* Checks if the binary tree rooted at r1 contains the binary tree 
     * rooted at r2 as a subtree somewhere within it.
     */

    public static boolean subTree( Node r1, Node r2) {

        if (r1 == null)
            return false; // big tree empty & subtree still not found.
        if (r1.key == r2.key) {
            if (matchTree(r1,r2)) return true;
        }
        return (subTree(r1.leftChild , r2) || subTree(r1.rightChild , r2)); 
    }

    /* 
      Checks if the binary tree rooted at r1 contains the 
      binary tree rooted at r2 as a subtree starting at r1.
     */

    public static boolean matchTree( Node r1, Node r2) {

        if (r2 == null && r1 == null) 
            return true; // nothing left in the subtree
        if (r1 == null || r2 == null) 
            return false; //  big tree empty & subtree still not found
        if (r1.key != r2.key) 
            return false;  // data doesn’t match
        return (matchTree(r1.leftChild, r2.leftChild) && 
                matchTree(r1.rightChild , r2.rightChild ));
    }
    // END OF SUBTREE CHECK 


        /* Creates tree by mapping the array left to right, top to bottom. */
    public  Node createTreeFromArray(int[] array) {

        if (array.length > 0) {

            root = new Node(array[0]);
            java.util.Queue<Node> queue = new java.util.LinkedList<Node>();
            queue.add(root);
            boolean done = false;
            int i = 1;

            while (!done) {

                Node r = (Node) queue.element();

                if (r.leftChild == null) {

                    r.leftChild = new Node(array[i]);
                    i++;
                    queue.add(r.leftChild);
                } 

                else if (r.rightChild == null) {
                    r.rightChild = new Node(array[i]);
                    i++;
                    queue.add(r.rightChild );
                } 

                else {
                    queue.remove();
                }

                if (i == array.length)
                    done = true;
            }

            return root;
        } 

        else {
            return null;
        }
    }


    // ALGORITHM TO FIND ALL THE PATHS TO CERTAIN SUM VALUE 

    public static void findSum( Node node, int sum, int[] path, int level) {

        if (node == null) {
            return;
        }

        /* Insert current node into path */
        path[level] = node.key; 

        int t = 0;
        for (int i = level; i >= 0; i--){

            t += path[i];
            if (t == sum) {
                print(path, i, level);
            }
        }

        findSum( node.leftChild, sum, path, level + 1);
        findSum( node.rightChild , sum, path, level + 1);

        /* Remove current node from path. Not strictly necessary, since we would
         * ignore this value, but it's good practice.
         */
        path[level] = Integer.MIN_VALUE; 
    }

    public static int depth( Node node) {

        if (node == null) {
            return 0;
        } 

        else {
            return 1 + Math.max(depth(node.leftChild), depth(node.rightChild));
        }
    }

    public static void findSum( Node node, int sum) {

        int depth = depth(node);
        int[] path = new int[depth];
        findSum(node, sum, path, 0);
    }

    private static void print(int[] path, int start, int end) {
        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
            System.out.print(path[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    // END PATH ALGORITHM 


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] myArr = {5, 3, 1, 4, 8, 2, 6}; 
        // int[] myArr = { 10,32,63,44,115,66,7,18,999 }; // sortedArrayToBST
        BinaryTree myTr = new BinaryTree();

        for( int j=0; j < myArr.length; j++){
            myTr.addNode(myArr[j]);
        }

        // Node n = BinaryTree.createMinimalBST(myArr);

        /*question 4-3
        create a binary tree with minimal height ( balanced tree )*/
        /*myTr.createMinimalBST(myArr);*/

        // System.out.println("The root is = "+myTr.root);
        myTr.inOrderTraverseTree(myTr.root);

        System.out.println("\n\n");

        /*get the height of the binary search tree*/
        /*System.out.println( "the height of the tree is = "+myTr.height(myTr.root));
        System.out.println("\n\n");*/

        /*question 4-1
        check whether the tree is balanced */

        /*boolean isBalanced = myTr.isBalanced(myTr.root);
        if (isBalanced) {
            System.out.println("The tree is balanced \n\n");
        }*/

        /*question 4-4
        create a linked list of all the nodes in the same level of the BST
        breadth first search ( BFS ) is used for implementation */ 

        /*ArrayList<LinkedList<Node>> list = createLevelLinkedList(myTr.root);
        printResult(list);*/

        /* ge parent of the elements */
        /*
        for(int j = 0; j < myArr.length ; j++){
            int checkParent = myArr[j];
            System.out.println("the parent of "+ checkParent +"  is = "+ myTr.getParent( checkParent) );
        }
        */      

        // using an integer value, get the node that contains that int element 
        /*Node myNode = myTr.getNode(44);
        System.out.println("Get my node = "+ myNode.key );  */

        /* get in-order successive node of certain node */
        /*int getInOrderSuccessive = 44 ;
        System.out.println( myTr.inorderSucc( myTr.getNode( getInOrderSuccessive)) );*/



        /* question 4-6 
        get the first common ancestor of two nodes */

        /*int firstNodeInteger = 7;
        int secondNodeInteger = 66;
        // try the first solution 
        System.out.println( myTr.commonAncestor( myTr.root, myTr.getNode(firstNodeInteger), myTr.getNode(secondNodeInteger) ));
        // try the second solution 
        System.out.println( myTr.commonAncestor2( myTr.root, myTr.getNode(firstNodeInteger), myTr.getNode(secondNodeInteger) ));
        */


        /* question 4-7 */
        /* check whether one tree is sub-set of the another tree */
        /*      
        int[] array1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13};
        int[] array2 = {2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11};

        Node t1 = myTr.createTreeFromArray(array1);
        Node t2 = myTr.createTreeFromArray(array2);

        if (containsTree(t1, t2))
            System.out.println("t2 is a subtree of t1");
        else
            System.out.println("t2 is not a subtree of t1");


        int[] array3 = {1, 2, 3};
        Node t3 = myTr.createTreeFromArray(array1);
        Node t4 = myTr.createTreeFromArray(array3);

        if (containsTree(t3, t4))
            System.out.println("t4 is a subtree of t3");
        else
            System.out.println("t4 is not a subtree of t3");
        */

        /*  question 4-8 
        algorithm to get all the paths equal to given value */

        /*int testValue  = 7;
        myTr.findSum( myTr.root, testValue );*/

    }

}
```

Comment: Your print is correct, what is wrong is the construction of your tree... Log the new nodes and you will see that some values are not inserted, and that you create *empty* nodes (node with value 0) in some cases... Why do you use so complicated algorithm (recursive cut of the array) for insertion? Given your method and the content of the array there is no way that your tree will be balanced... Is balanced a requirement? What do you really want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see the `balancedBST` in your code. Did you mean the method `createMinimalBST(int arr[], int start, int end, Node newNode)`?

If so, then based on this call

```
createMinimalBST(array, 0, array.length - 1, root)
```

I deduce `start` and `end` parameters are *inclusive* indices of the subarray to be converted into a subtree. For the single-item array you have `start == end` — but then the first line of the method will discard that item:

```
if ( end <= start ) return;
```

leaving you with a new node with no key assigned.

And the whole method is overcomplicated and thus unreadable. KISS! For example:

```
private  Node createBalancedTree(int arr[], int start, int end){

    if ( end < start ) return null;        // empty array -> empty tree

    int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;   // avoid overflow

    // create a tip node
    Node node = new Node( arr[mid] );

    // convert remaining subarrays (if any) into subtrees
    node.leftChild = createBalancedTree( arr, start, mid - 1 );
    node.rightChild = createBalancedTree( arr, mid + 1, end );

    return node;
} 

public void createBalancedTree( int array[] ) {
    // convert the array into a tree and plant it in this
    root = createBalancedTree( array, 0, array.length - 1 );
}
```

Note however I removed 'BS' from the method name. The routine never checks the ordering of array items, so the resulting tree is balanced, but might be NOT-BST if the array isn't sorted!

If you want the resulting tree with a proper ordering you either need to sort the array prior to the 'build-a-tree' call or you have to add nodes one by one with an `addNode(int key)` method.

And if you want to build a balanced BST, then you need a new `addNodeBalanced` method...

(There is a load of other issues with your code, <del>like a forever-recurring `height(Node root)`</del>, but I limit myself here to the part you pointed in your question.)

**EDIT**
The note about `height(Node root)` turned out to be false.

Comment: You are right, I changed the method name and I should have mention that. I see your code, it's better and works in the program. 
I'm actually preparing myself for a tech interview and this is part of the preparation. May I ask what's the issue with height ( Node root ) method ? 
Thanks.

Comment: Nothing, it's OK. My mistake, I haven't noticed you masked the `BinaryTree` class `root` member with the `Node root` parameter to the method. So I thought that assignment `Node focusNode = root;` causes the method to loop over and over from the tree's `root`, thus never completing (unless the `root` is the only node). Such mistake would be less likely if you used distinct names for distinct purposes, e.g. gave the parameter the name `Node focusNode` (and dropped the assignment).

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `root` in your `bbst()` method instead of declaring `n`.

```
public void bbst(int array[]) {

    root = new TreeNode();
    balancedBST(array, 0, array.length - 1, root);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed the code according to your suggestion. However, it still not prints correctly.